# Unable to reset matt-autocomplete or de-select matt-option in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, autocomplete

I have a matt-autocomplete that I want to reset ( or de-select the matt-option ) with a press of a button.

I have tried various options:

1. Reset the formControl
2. Change the value of matt-option (to trigger a change event)
3. Change the value of filteredOption
4. Set the value to a default one

None of these options seem to work properly, I have looked around hoping there could be a method such matt-autocomplete.reset() but could fine anything (that would have been nice!).

Now matt-option has has a readonly property (_selected), but again I can't find a walkaround to change that value

this is the template:

```
<div class="bordered--bottom msg__field" matAutocompleteOrigin #origin="matAutocompleteOrigin">
  <label for="recipient" class="field-title">{{'To' | r58translator:languageId}}:</label>
  <input type="text"
    id="recipient"
    matInput
    #contactInput
    [formControl]="searchControl"
    [matAutocomplete]="contact"
    [matAutocompleteConnectedTo]="origin">
  <mat-autocomplete #contact="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayName" (optionSelected)="setContactId($event.option)">
    <mat-option #mattOption autoActiveFirstOption 
      *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" 
      style="{{option.id === 0 ? 'display: none' : ''}}">
      <div class="contact-option">
        <div class="contact-icon">
          <img *ngIf="option.imgUrl" class="contact__img"
            src="{{option.imgUrl}}" alt="{{option.contactName}} profile image">
          <span *ngIf="!option.imgUrl" class="folder__initial-icon">
            {{option.contactName | nameToInitials}}
          </span>
       </div>
       <div class="contact-details">
          <span class="contact-name">Contact id: {{ option.id }}</span>
       </div>
       <div (click)="removeContact($event)" class="remove">
         <span *ngIf="contactId === option.id" class="material-icons" >cancel</span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <span class="copy-options" (click)="hasCc = !hasCc">Cc</span>
  <span class="copy-options" (click)="hasBcc = !hasBcc">Bcc</span>
</div>
```

and the TS

```
export class NewMessageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('mattOption') mattOption: MatOption;
  @ViewChild('contact') mattAutoComplete: MatAutocomplete;
  @ViewChild('contactInput') contactInput: ElementRef;

  @ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
  defaultOption: Contact = {
    id: 0,
    email: '',
    contactName: '',
    imgUrl: '',
  };

  @Output() cancelNewMsg: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  searchControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  filteredOptions: Observable<Contact[]>;
  public languageId: number;
  public messageForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    contactId: 0,
    cc: [],
    bcc: [],
    subject: '',
    content: '',
    threadId: '',
    attachment: []
  } as MessageModel);
  public user: User = typeof USER !== 'undefined' ? USER : {id: 3019, username: 'johnsmith@r58.com', fullName: 'John Smith'};
  public contacts: Contact[] = [];
  public hasCc = false;
  public hasBcc = false;
  public contactId = 0;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>,
              private translatorPipe: TranslatorPipe,
              private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private renderer: Renderer2,
              private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select(getLanguageId).subscribe((res: {id: number}) => {
      this.languageId = res.id;
    });

    this.http.get<Contact[]>(`a url`).subscribe((resp: Contact[]) => {
      this.contacts = [this.defaultOption, ...resp];
      this.filteredOptions = this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    }, error => console.log('Could not load contacts.'));
  }

  public displayName(contact: Contact): string {
    return contact && contact.contactName ? `${ contact.contactName } <${ contact.email }>` : '';
  }

  private _filter(value: string | object): any {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      return this.contacts.filter((option: Contact) => {
        return option.contactName.toLowerCase().includes(value.toString().toLowerCase()) || option.email.toLowerCase().includes(value.toString().toLowerCase())
      });
    } else {
      return this.contacts;
    }
  }

  public removeContact(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.autoTrigger.closePanel();
    this.filteredOptions = this.searchControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.defaultOption),
      map(value => this._filter(''))
    );
    this.contactId = 0;
  }

  public setContactId(contact: any) {
    const newContactId = contact.value.id ? contact.value.id : 0;
    this.messageForm.patchValue({ contactId: newContactId });
    this.contactId = newContactId;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to either reset the autocomplete or simply de-select the currently selected matt-option when I click on div.remove?